# How convert git_tree_entry to git_tree

Tags: libgit2

Same as title. How convert git_tree_entry to git_tree in libgit2?

```
if ((error = git_tree_entry_bypath(&source_tree_entry, root_tree, path)) < 0)
    return GIT_ENOTFOUND;

// How convert source_tree_entry to tree here?

entries_count = git_tree_entrycount(tree);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't convert it, you ask for the tree you want. The tree entry tells you its name, mode and id. If you want that tree, you look it up.

```
git_tree_lookup(&tree, repo, git_tree_entry_id(tree_entry))
```